# "Operation not permitted" when execute shell script in mac app

Tags: xcode, macos, shell

I'm developing the mac applivation on Xcode,
I want to execute some shell script,

```
cp file ~/Library/.....
```

It always show "Operation not permitted",but I'm sure that it can be execute at terminal.

I'm trying to edit the "Install Owner" and "Install Permissions" inside the Xcode, but it still not work.

Thanks

Comment: is the destination writable?  if you do this in "`Terminal.app`" (a command line prompt), would your "`cp`" work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem, it cause from Xcode sandbox mode, it work after turn off it.

Answer (score 11):

To turn off sandboxing 
go to
`Your target` -> `Capabilities` -> `App Sandbox` `(Turn the switch off)`

Comment: I searched high and low for this answer - ChatGPT was clueless. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

For me I had to go to Build Settings -> User Script Sandboxing -> false

Enable App Sandboxing is a different setting and was already set to false but has no impact on Run Scripts.

Comment: I think it's a new option introduced in Xcode 15

Comment: Project > Build Settings > `ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING`: no

Comment: Thanks!  Knew it had to have been a setting somewhere. 