# Run Shell Script from Xcode button

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to get a button in Xcode to run a shell script with clicked.

This works

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let path = "/usr/bin/say"
        let arguments = ["hello world"]     
        sender.isEnabled = false
        let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
        task.waitUntilExit()
        sender.isEnabled = true
    }
```

But when I try this it does not work to run a script from the Desktop

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: NSButton) {
     let path = "/bin/bash"
     let arguments = ["~/Desktop/test.sh"]      
     sender.isEnabled = false
     let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
     task.waitUntilExit()     
     sender.isEnabled = true
 }
```

I get this error output in Xcode

```
/bin/bash: ~/Desktop/test.sh: No such file or directory
```

If anyone can help me with some help or example that would great. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's not able to process the `~` as home dir. Try the full absolute path

Comment: Hello. I tried and got this

/bin/bash: /Users/atejada/Desktop/test.sh: Operation not permitted

Comment: Ok, so it got past the first problem. Not familiar with XCode. Check permissions on that file. Are you running this process as yourself?

Comment: Great. Yes myself. The script is executable. I can run it via terminal

Comment: Not sure what to do then. I'd update your question with the latest error message as it is now a different problem

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689647/operation-not-permitted-when-execute-shell-script-in-mac-app

Comment: sounds like that might, but can't figure out how to turn off sandbox on xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off Xcode sandbox mode, it will fix the issue

Comment: Thank you. 

For anyone that has this problem too.

Go to the build settings of your target.
Make sure that you have "All" selected instead of "Basic"
Type "entitlements" into the search box.
The result is the build setting where you can specify where your entitlements file is located.

Answer (score 1):

```
  func shell(_ args: String) -> String {
    var outstr = ""
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", args]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
        outstr = output as String
    }
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return outstr
}
```

This Function returns output of Bash Script you're trying to run

```
 let cmd = "for i in $(ifconfig -lu); do if ifconfig $i | grep -q \"status: active\" ; then echo $i; fi; done"
```

Above Code Demonstrate how to use it.